# Optimizing iFrame performance

Tags: performance, optimization, iframe

I'm using iFrame in my site to include other third party site in my site. How can I optimize its performance?

- Are iFrame resources get cached?
- If yes, then who is responsible for configuring it?
- Should I configure caching of iFrame or should owner of third party website has to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'performance' to an iFrame. An iFrame is merely an HTML tag that opens up space up in the current page to load an external HTML file.

That external HTML file would be cached by your browser as your browser settings see fit.

In terms of server caching and performance of the page it is loading, that's entirely up to the owner of that particular page and their own server/network set up.